# SQL how to collapse multiple columns into two columns, one for column heading and the second for column value

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

If the input data looks like this:

| Key | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| keyA | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 |
| keyB | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 |

How can I convert it to look like this?

| Key | ColTitle | ColVal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| keyA | Col1 | val1 |
| keyA | Col2 | val2 |
| keyA | Col3 | val3 |
| keyA | Col4 | val4 |
| keyB | Col1 | val1 |
| keyB | Col2 | val2 |
| keyB | Col3 | val3 |
| keyB | Col4 | val4 |

Answer (score 0):

One method is `union all`:

```
select key, 'Col1' as coltitle, col1 as colval
from t
union all
select key, 'Col2' as coltitle, col2 as colval
from t
union all
select key, 'Col3' as coltitle, col3 as colval
from t
union all
select key, 'Col4' as coltitle, col4 as colval
from t
```